# Yocto project installation error

Tags: software-installation, compiling

I installed the Yocto project in Ubuntu 12.04 desktop. I followed steps what they given in the yocto website 
[Supported Linux Distributions](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.5.1/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#detailed-supported-distros).

```
$ sudo apt-get install gawk wget git-core diffstat unzip texinfo gcc-multilib
  build-essential chrpath
$ sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev xterm
$ sudo apt-get install make xsltproc docbook-utils fop dblatex xmlto
$ sudo apt-get install autoconf automake libtool libglib2.0-dev
```

After installations I did this steps

```
$ cd ~
$ git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky
$ cd poky
$ git checkout -b dora origin/dora
$ source oe-init-build-env
$ bitbake adt-installer
```

I got this errors

```
Loading cache: 100% |###########################################| ETA:  00:00:00
Loaded 1188 entries from dependency cache.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION        = "1.20.0"
BUILD_SYS         = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING   = "Ubuntu-12.04"
TARGET_SYS        = "i586-poky-linux"
MACHINE           = "qemux86"
DISTRO            = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION    = "1.5.1"
TUNE_FEATURES     = "m32 i586"
TARGET_FPU        = ""
meta              
meta-yocto        
meta-yocto-bsp    = "dora:84c2763fa0bf08a83caa2c5ee532b5bef2ff918b"

NOTE: Preparing runqueue
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
WARNING: Failed to fetch URL ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/readline/readline-6.2.tar.gz;name=archive, attempting MIRRORS if available
WARNING: Failed to fetch URL ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/readline/readline-6.2-patches/readline62-001;name=patch1;apply=yes;striplevel=0, attempting MIRRORS if available
ERROR: Fetcher failure: Fetch command failed with exit code 4, no output
ERROR: Function failed: Fetcher failure for URL: 'ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/readline/readline-6.2-patches/readline62-001;name=patch1;apply=yes;striplevel=0'. Unable to fetch URL from any source.
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/openstack/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/readline-native/6.2-r4/temp/log.do_fetch.32384
ERROR: Task 347 (virtual:native:/home/openstack/poky/meta/recipes-core/readline/readline_6.2.bb, do_fetch) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 190 tasks of which 155 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
No currently running tasks (190 of 373)

Summary: 1 task failed:
  virtual:native:/home/openstack/poky/meta/recipes-core/readline/readline_6.2.bb, do_fetch
Summary: There were 2 WARNING messages shown.
Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

How to install Yocto project? Anyone help me.

Comment: At first glance this looks like a bug in the installer, it looks like it's parsing its configuration file incorrectly and ends up fetching `ftp://foo;settings` instead of `ftp://foo`.

Comment: [at first glance](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/at+first+glance)

Answer (score 0):

In yocto, do_fetching process means getting packages or libraries via ethernet or local storage.

```
ERROR: Function failed: Fetcher failure for URL: 'ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/readline/readline-6.2-patches/readline62-001;name=patch1;apply=yes;striplevel=0'. Unable to fetch URL from any source.
```

This message means your URI of package is incorrect or broken.
I think you should validate that the URI is correct first.

Answer (score 0):

As mentionner in previous answer, the problem here is that Yocto  is unable to fetch readline archive which is necessary for it to build its toolchain.

You can dig in the ful log (/home/openstack/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/readline-native/6.2-r4/temp/log.do_fetch.32384) as mentionned in Yocto error to have a better idea about the cause of the failure.

You may also try to fetch the URL manually (wget or curl to ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/readline/readline-6.2.tar.gz) to ensure that this is not a connectivity problem.

The same archive is also accessible using HTTP, so if your problem is accessing FTP you may create a `.bbappend` that supersed the SRCURI to target it using HTTP protocol.